# NHibernate: LINQ to NHibernate self join

Tags: sql, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I'm trying to achieve the following SQL Statement using LINQ to NHibernate:

```
SELECT a.JOB_ID ID FROM SERVICE_DATA a WHERE STEP_ID = x and (STATUS = 'Success' or STATUS = 'Skipped') 
  AND a.JOB_ID not in (SELECT JOB_ID FROM SERVICE_DATA WHERE JOB_ID = a.JOB_ID AND STATUS = 'Error') 
  AND a.JOB_ID not in (SELECT JOB_ID FROM SERVICE_DATA WHERE STEP_ID = y and (STATUS = 'Success' or STATUS = 'Skipped' or STATUS = 'Error'));
```

Currently i'm able to select everything expect the 1st NOT IN self join condition using:

```
DetachedCriteria secondSubCriteria = DetachedCriteria.For<ServiceData>()
            .SetProjection(Projections.Property("JobId"))
            .Add(Restrictions.Eq("StepId", stepId))
            .Add(Restrictions.Disjunction()
                .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Status", "Success"))
                .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Status", "Skipped"))
                .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Status", "Error")));

var data = session.CreateCriteria<ServiceData>()
                .Add(Restrictions.Eq("StepId", stepId))
                .Add(Restrictions.Disjunction()
                    .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Status", "Success"))
                    .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Status", "Skipped")))
              //.Add(Subqueries.PropertyNotIn("JobId", ???))
                .Add(Subqueries.PropertyNotIn("JobId", secondSubCriteria))
                .List<ServiceData>()
                .Take(1)
                .FirstOrDefault();
```

How do i get the self join based on the column JOB_ID to work on the first subcriteria in the example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying around i found the answer myself, for anyone having the same problem specify a table alias in the Criteria() constructor and refer in the other queries to this.

```
 DetachedCriteria firstSubCriteria = DetachedCriteria.For<ServiceData>("x")
        .SetProjection(Projections.Property("x.JobId"))
        .Add(Restrictions.EqProperty("x.JobId", "s.JobId"))
        .Add(Restrictions.Not(Restrictions.Eq("x.Status", "Error")));

 DetachedCriteria secondSubCriteria = DetachedCriteria.For<ServiceData>()
        .SetProjection(Projections.Property("JobId"))
        .Add(Restrictions.Eq("StepId", stepId))
        .Add(Restrictions.Disjunction()
            .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Status", "Success"))
            .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Status", "Skipped"))
            .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Status", "Error")));  

var data = session.CreateCriteria<ServiceData>("s")
        .Add(Restrictions.Eq("StepId", stepId))
        .Add(Restrictions.Disjunction()
             .Add(Restrictions.Eq("s.Status", "Success"))
             .Add(Restrictions.Eq("s.Status", "Skipped")))
        .Add(Subqueries.PropertyNotIn("s.JobId", firstSubCriteria))
        .Add(Subqueries.PropertyNotIn("s.JobId", secondSubCriteria))
        .List<ServiceData>()
        .Take(1)
        .FirstOrDefault();
```